# Is there a way to create a custom class that I can mutate?

Tags: ios, swift, properties

Currently, I've made a custom class called SongNames. Here's the code for it:

```
import Foundation

class songAttributes {
private var _songTitle: String!
private var _songURL: String!

var songTitle: String {
    return _songTitle
}

init(songTitle: String, songURL: String) {
    _songURL = songURL
    _songTitle = songTitle

}
var songURL: String {
    return _songURL
}

}
```

I have no problem setting values for this class. For instance, I might write:

```
var songAttribute = songAttributes(songTitle: "That's What I Like", url: "some url")
```

However, if I try to change the properties of my variable that I just created, like saying:

```
songAttribute.songTitle = "Locked Out of Heaven"
```

I get the message: "error: songTitle is a get only property"

That being said, is there a way to mess with my SongName class so that these properties can be changed, and not just get-only?

Comment: Why are you using a private backing variable?  Just expose the string property. Also, there is no reason for the private variables to be implicitly unwrapped optionals.

Comment: Knowing that having a setter/getter in your example is an overkilled, I'd use a `struct` over `class` since you are manipulating data. (struct value type, class reference type) this have a great effect when it comes to copy (or make multiple copy) of that data

Comment: This Java style of using getter/setter methods to wrap access to private instance variables is COMPLETELY UNNECESSARY IN SWIFT. Instance variables don't directly exist in Swift. In your example, you have manually created a getter, `songTitle`, for `_songTitle`, which is itself a getter for a hidden instance variable, call it `__songTitle`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want the properties to be settable then there is no need for the dance with the private properties. Also, the properties should not be implicitly unwrapped, since you are setting them in the initialiser.

```
import Foundation

class SongAttributes {
    var songTitle: String
    var songURL: String

    init(songTitle: String, songURL: String) {
        self.songURL = songURL
        self.songTitle = songTitle

    }
}
```

Note that, by convention, class and struct names should start with a capital letter.

Comment: This is the proper way.

Comment: Looks like you beat me to the punch. Several other people waded into the weeds about how to make custom getters and setters, which is pointless.

Comment: I know. Some sort of weird Objective-C or Java nonsense. Even Objective-C has hidden the ivars behind implicit setter/getters  for several years

Comment: Yup. That's a holdover from Objective-C, and even there it's usually hidden.

Answer (score 3):

You are doing a lot of unnecessary work. You have private variables backing all of your public variables, and have made your public variables computed properties. Get rid of all that. It's needless complexity:

```
import Foundation

class songAttributes {

    var songTitle: String 
    var songURL: String

    init(songTitle: String, songURL: String) {
        self.songURL = songURL
        self.songTitle = songTitle
    }
}
```

By default properties are read/write, so you don't need to do anything special.

The pattern of having private backing variables that start with the `_` prefix is largely a holdover from Objective-C, and rarely needed in Swift.

Comment: And, as Paul pointed out, your class names should start with a capital letter.